# How to use LinearRegression across groups in DataFrame?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

Let us say my spark DataFrame (DF) looks like

```
id | age | earnings| health 
----------------------------
1  | 34  | 65      | 8
2  | 65  | 12      | 4
2  | 20  | 7       | 10
1  | 40  | 75      | 7
.  | ..  | ..      | ..
```

and I would like to group the DF, apply a function (say linear 
regression which depends on multiple columns - two columns in this case - 
of aggregated DF) on each aggregated DF and get output like

```
id | intercept| slope 
----------------------
1  |   ?      |  ? 
2  |   ?      |  ?
```

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lr_object = LinearRegression()

def linear_regression(ith_DF):
    # Note: for me it is necessary that ith_DF should contain all 
    # data within this function scope, so that I can apply any 
    # function that needs all data in ith_DF

    X = [i.earnings for i in ith_DF.select("earnings").rdd.collect()]
    y = [i.health for i in ith_DF.select("health").rdd.collect()]

    lr_object.fit(X, y)
    return lr_object.intercept_, lr_object.coef_[0]

coefficient_collector = []

# following iteration is not possible in spark as 'GroupedData' 
# object is not iterable, please consider it as pseudo code

for ith_df in df.groupby("id"): 
    c, m = linear_regression(ith_df)
    coefficient_collector.append((float(c), float(m)))

model_df = spark.createDataFrame(coefficient_collector, ["intercept", "slope"])
model_df.show()
```

Comment: The question seems similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/43742926/1305344 with the only(?) difference of using `LinearRegression` not `QuantileDiscretizer`. Looks like a very hot topic these days.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski thanks for the input. but the problem is to apply a custom aggregation function which takes 2 columns of grouped portion of Dataframe, unlike xxxx.agg({'colA': sum}) where sum works on only one column colA. Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to do in the custom aggregation function?

Comment: If I am able to grab the ith_df, then I can run various predictive models(feature columns: x1, x2, x3 , .....xn-1 and target column: xn) on each ith_df.

Comment: Ohk...thanks. but it has performance impact when concatenating each dataframe back to form a single dataframe. That is why I wanted to do inline  aggregation on each dataframe.

Comment: "performance impact"?! Care to elaborate? Where would be any performance degradation?

Comment: I cringe to even say it but maybe use for loops??? and then use `reduce(DataFrame.unionByName)` ??

Answer (score 4):

I think this can be done since Spark 2.3 using pandas_UDF.  In fact, there is an example of fitting grouped regressions on the announcement of pandas_UDFs here:

[Introducing Pandas UDF for Python](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/10/30/introducing-vectorized-udfs-for-pyspark.html)

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do is to `filter` the main DataFrame to create smaller DataFrames and do the processing, say a linear regression.

You can then execute the linear regression in parallel (on separate threads using the same `SparkSession` which is thread-safe) and the main DataFrame cached.

That should give you the full power of Spark.

p.s. My limited understanding of that part of Spark makes me think that a very similar approach is used for [grid search-based model selection](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-tuning.html) in Spark MLlib and also [TensorFrames](https://github.com/databricks/tensorframes) which is "Experimental TensorFlow binding for Scala and Apache Spark".